# Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column for new online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

There are several answers about this online but they don't appear to work anymore with the sharepoint online experience.

I set up the title/linked field as the wrong column and want to change it. The existing instructions say to use sharepoint designer and add these fields to the viewfield tag:

```
<FieldRef Name="COLUMNNAME" linkToItem="TRUE" linkToItemAllowed="TRUE" listItemMenu="TRUE"/>
```

I did this and it has no effect. I think it might have something to do with the current field which looks like this:

```
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
```

This is interesting because the actual name of that column is "status", but it appears as LinkTitle.